# How to return associative array of column names and only defined values with Perl::DBI?

Tags: perl, dbi

I have used:

```
my @ar = $stm->fetchrow_array
#to remove undefined
@ar = grep defined, @ar;
```

But that does not show the column name as reference

So I used

```
my $rec = $stm->fetchrow_arrayref
```

But it is difficult to remove undefined values and the array refernce is not the column names.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $rec = $stm->fetchrow_hashref;

my @to_delete = grep { !defined($rec->{$_}) } keys %$rec;

delete @{$rec}{@to_delete};
```

Comment: Mandatory warning about the `*_hashref` methods: if your query returns multiple columns with the same name, only one of them will be added to the hash. Also, the database server determines the name for fields like `COUNT(*)`, which may cause clashes with other columns. You can use column aliases in your SQL statement to avoid this, e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*) AS foo` instead of just `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: It is understatement that having multiple columns with identical names in query is a bad practice.

Comment: @mpapec, No, it's not, since the columns could be in different tables.

Comment: @ikegami still, I consider that as a bad practice purely from sql query perspective (there are column aliases to address this problem).

Comment: @mpapec, The converse (needlessly using `AS`) sounds like the worse practice to me.